# Ant Junit5 : org.junit.platform.commons.util.PreconditionViolationException: Could not load class with name

Tags: ant, junit5

I am trying to migrate from Junit4 to Junit5. Here is the list of dependencies I am using :

[Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ5vZ.png)

I am able to run the tests using Eclipse, but not able to run them using Ant. Here is what stack trace looks like:

```
Jun 29, 2018 1:50:39 AM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-vintage' failed to discover tests
org.junit.platform.commons.util.PreconditionViolationException: Could not load class with name: microservicehelper.AuthMicroserviceHelperTest
    at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.ClassSelector.lambda$getJavaClass$0(ClassSelector.java:73)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.ClassSelector.getJavaClass(ClassSelector.java:72)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.ClassSelectorResolver.resolve(ClassSelectorResolver.java:29)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.VintageDiscoverer.collectTestClasses(VintageDiscoverer.java:64)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.VintageDiscoverer.discover(VintageDiscoverer.java:51)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.discover(VintageTestEngine.java:61)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:130)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:117)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junitlauncher.JUnitLauncherTask.execute(JUnitLauncherTask.java:93)
    at JUnit5.main(JUnit5.java:154)
```

Comment: Are you sure the class is on the classpath?

Comment: Yes class is on the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently adding Junit5 Dependencies in ANT_HOME/lib fixed the issue. (I already mentioned them in the classpath of Build.xml)